# how can i add the unallocated space to my linux partition?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

[image: gparted view]

I would like to add the unallocated space to my linux partition p5. Cannot resize while mounted in read only. Is it possible to change this while booted to linux on that partition? gparted view linked above.

Comment: Boot into a LiveUSB, then you can make changes. Make a backup first and be patient: The unallocated space is on the wrong side, so the process is risky and will take time.

Comment: @user535733 oh no. Would it make sense to make a backup and then delete partitions that aren't windows, resize and reinstall the backup?

Comment: Sure, that method will also accomplish what you want...assuming your backup is good. The "best" method is the method that you understand and have the skills to troubleshoot and recover when something goes wrong. Pro Tip: Re-partitioning is *inherently risky*. Before touching partitions, I have all data on all partitions backed up, install media for all OS on-hand, and complete notes on how to rebuild the system from scratch (customizations, keys, accounts, etc). Most are rarely needed, but on a really bad day you'll be glad you prepared for the worst.

Comment: @user535733 thanks for the response I am kind of a n00b here. What do you recommend for a backup tool and if needed to reinstall should it be stored USB? I don't have any data that's in danger of being lost at this point I would just like to have the dual boot working and utilize the space. If there's a good method to go about it and a step by step to get back up and running id be happy to give it a shot :)